# Facebook messenger share video not working - connection error

Tags: ios, facebook-messenger

I am trying to use the facebook messenger SDK to share a video (as described here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger/ios).

I can share images just fine, but when trying to share it a video it fails due to a connection error.

No error output in the console or anything, hitting the retry button prompts the same result.

```
NSString *filepath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:str ofType:@"mp4"];
 NSData *videoData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:str];
 [FBSDKMessengerSharer shareVideo:videoData withOptions:nil];
```

I have checked the values in the debugger, they do correctly refer to the videos location (when I got it wrong earlier, the returned NSData was null).

Comment: Try posting some code

Comment: Video may be too large. Try and post a smaller video size.

Comment: Thanks for the idea but the videos are 3 seconds long